# Validating property failed google datastore

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following model based on ndb.Model. I am trying to validate the model,date_of_birth property.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class CFCSocialUser(ndb.Model):

    def clean_dob(value):
        if value.year < 1900:
            raise Exception("Year cannot be less than 1900")

    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    userid = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    date_of_birth = ndb.DateProperty(validator=clean_dob)

    @staticmethod
    def create_new_user(name, email, date_of_birth):
        app = CFCSocialUser(username=name,
                            email=email,
                            date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
        app.put()
```

The following is my unit test which is supposed to test the validation.

```
from datetime import date

from unittest import TestCase
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from mainsite.rainbow.models.CFCSocialUser import CFCSocialUser


def create_user_before_1900():
    user = CFCSocialUser.create_new_user(name="Vinay Joseph",
                                         email="xxx@xxx.com",
                                         date_of_birth=date(1899, 3, 11))


class TestCFCSocialUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
        ndb.get_context().clear_cache()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def test_validation(self):
        self.assertRaises(Exception, create_user_before_1900())
```

I get the following error when I try to run my unit test

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_validation (tests.test_CFCSocialUser.TestCFCSocialUser)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/cfc-social-media-website/tests/test_CFCSocialUser.py", line 26, in test_validation
    self.assertRaises(Exception, create_user_before_1900())
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/cfc-social-media-website/tests/test_CFCSocialUser.py", line 12, in create_user_before_1900
    date_of_birth=date(1899, 3, 11))
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/cfc-social-media-website/mainsite/rainbow/models/CFCSocialUser.py", line 19, in create_new_user
    date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
  File "/Users/vinay/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2947, in __init__
    self._set_attributes(kwds)
  File "/Users/vinay/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2993, in _set_attributes
    prop._set_value(self, value)
  File "/Users/vinay/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1145, in _set_value
    value = self._do_validate(value)
  File "/Users/vinay/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1094, in _do_validate
    newvalue = self._validator(self, value)
TypeError: clean_dob() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clean_dob()` is an instance member function and should get a `self` as a first argument.

Like:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  def clean_dob(self, value):
    pass
```

Or you can define it as a static method:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  @staticmethod
  def clean_dob(value):
    pass
```

Or move outside of class:

```
def clean_dob(value):
  pass

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The App Engine [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options) say that a validator function is called with two arguments: `prop` and `value`, so you need to change your function to:

```
def clean_dob(prop, value):
    if value.year < 1900:
        raise Exception("Year cannot be less than 1900")
```

The prop argument is an instance of the property being validated, not the model class, so it should be placed outside the class body as a standalone function.  Leaving it inside the class is confusing for readers of the code who might assume it to be an instance method of the model.